# How to display specific information from JSON API?

Tags: json, ajax, wordpress

How can i display the value of a specific variable stored in an JSON API array?

For e.g. how could i display the current Bitcoin price in USD in a specific wordpress post using coinmarketcaps JSON API (https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/)?

The API gives me the following output:

```
[
{
    "id": "bitcoin", 
    "name": "Bitcoin", 
    "symbol": "BTC", 
    "rank": "1", 
    "price_usd": "3351.98", 
    "price_btc": "1.0", 
    "24h_volume_usd": "1455740000.0", 
    "market_cap_usd": "55289274334.0", 
    "available_supply": "16494512.0", 
    "total_supply": "16494512.0", 
    "percent_change_1h": "0.55", 
    "percent_change_24h": "3.45", 
    "percent_change_7d": "17.52", 
    "last_updated": "1502145551"
}
]
```

I only need to display the value of "price_usd" tho.

I've tried to do it this way, but it didn't work:

```
<script>

    var btcPrice;

    function UpdateBtcPrice(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result){
                btcPrice = result[0].price_usd;
            },
        error: function(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function to execute the request:

```
        var btcPrice;

        function UpdateBtcPrice(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(result){
                    btcPrice = result[0].price_usd;
                },
            error: function(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
            });
        }

        UpdateBtcPrice();
```

Comment: I know that. I still cant get it to work tho. I thought that i have to add the function to the functions.php file of my current wordpress theme and can anfterwards request the function whereever i want it. Sadly wordpress gets broken as soon as i ad the new function to its functions.php

Comment: @Voxcon - You can't use javascript or jQuery inside functions.php, you have to put this function inside template file, where it can be accessed from client - browser.

Comment: ah i see. Saved the function as UpdateBtcPrice.js in the js folder and now i can access it via php function call! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code

```
<?php
    //get data with api call
    $response = file_get_contents('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/');
    $response = json_decode($response);

    echo $response[0]->price_usd;//print the value
?>
```

Comment: Souvik Sikdar thank you very much! Your method is much simpler and works great!